# How to apply a randomforest classifier to all of the dataset, a small section at a time in python

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, dataset, random-forest

So I am doing a Kaggle Competition and the size of the testing dataset it 880,000 rows long. And I want to apply a random forest classifier on 10,000 row sections of it. But still apply it to all of it.
Here is how my classifyer is set up

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100)
# Training data features, skip the first column 'Crime Category'
train_features = train[:, 1:]

# 'Crime Category' column values
train_target = train[:, 0]

clf = clf.fit(train_features, train_target)
score = clf.score(train_features, train_target)
"Mean accuracy of Random Forest: {0}".format(score)
```

I used this to train my model and get the accuracy. I made the training data smaller so it would be faster for me to get results. But in order for me to submit to Kaggle I need to predict the testing data. Basically I want to do this:

```
test_x = testing_data[:, 1:]
print('-',*38)
for every 10,000 rows in test_x
   test_ y = clf.predict(value)
   print(".")
   add the values to an array then do the next 10,000 rows
```

For every 10,000 rows I want to predict the values, add the predicted values somewhere then do the next 10,000 rows. Whenever I d all 880,000 rows at once my computer just freezes. I am hoping that by doing 10,000 rows at a time and using the print(".") I will get a progress bar. I changed the test.csv from a `pandas` `dataframe` to `values` using the `test= test.values`.

I included as much information as I could, if you need more information let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `pd.DataFrame`, you can iterate over chunks of the `index` and `concat` the results using a new `DataFrame`. For `np.array`, use [`np.array_split`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html).

```
def chunks(l, n):
    """ Yield successive n-sized chunks from l."""
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i + n]

test_x = pd.DataFrame(test_x)
test_result = pd.DataFrame()
for chunk in chunks(test_x.index, 10000):
    test_data = test_x.ix[chunk]
    test_result = pd.concat([test_result, pd.DataFrame(clf.predict(test_data))])
```

Comment: it gives in an AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index' because the test_x is a numpy.ndarray.

Comment: Looks like you are using `numpy arrays`, not pandas `DataFrames`. You have the choice to create one by using `test_x = DataFrame(test_x)` or need to rewrite for `numpy`, for instance using `np.array_split`.

Comment: I ended up chaning my test_x back to a pandas then I got this error   'cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object'  @Stefan Jansen

Comment: See update - need to convert the output of `clf.predict(test_data))` to `pd.DataFrame()` as well.

Comment: You're welcome. It's good practice here to mark a question as solved by accepting an answer.

Comment: Sorry just did. Thank again!

Answer (score 0):

I'm making the assumption your index is sequential integers...

```
groups = test_x.groupby(test_x.index // 10000)
groups.apply(clf.predict)
```

If index is not sequential integers this is a possibility...

```
groups = test.groupby(test.reset_index().index // 10000)
```

Heres a full example...

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

iris = load_iris()
df = pd.DataFrame(iris.data, columns=iris.feature_names)

train, test = (df[:100], df[100:])
y_train, y_test = (iris.target[:100], iris.target[100:])

clf = RandomForestClassifier()
clf.fit(train, y_train)

groups = test.groupby(test.index // 10)
groups.apply(clf.predict)
```

Output is a Pandas series of lists of predictions...

```
10    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
11    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
12    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
13    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
14    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

In 2018, the fastai 0.7 library from fast.ai has a set_rf_samples() function that does this with some special features. If you land on this page highly suggest looking into it. You can watch the Intro to Machine Learning MOOC with the implementation details on Jeremy Howard's YouTube channel.